# Structure Map - Replace Interface with mock object at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, moq, structuremap

I am doing some integration tests for my OWIN based Web API. I am using structure map as DI container. In one of the cases, I need to mock out an API call ( can't include it as part of the test).

How would I go about doing this using Structure Map? I have done it using SimpleInjector but the code base I am working on is using Structure Map and I can't figure out how I would do this.

Solution with SimpleInjector:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var config = new HttpConfiguration();
   app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register(config));

   // Register IOC containers
   IOCConfig.RegisterServices(config);
}
```

ICOCConfig:

```
 public static Container Container { get; set; }
 public static void RegisterServices(HttpConfiguration config)
 {            
    Container = new Container();

    // Register            
    config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(Container);
 }
```

And in my Integration test, I mock out the interface that calls the other API.

```
private TestServer testServer;
private Mock<IShopApiHelper> apiHelper;

[TestInitialize]
public void Intitialize()
{
      testServer= TestServer.Create<Startup>();
      apiHelper= new Mock<IShopApiHelper>();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_Test()
{
      //Arrange
      apiHelper.Setup(x => x.CreateClientAsync())
               .Returns(Task.FromResult(true);

      IOCConfig.Container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
      IOCConfig.Container.Register<IShopApiHelper>(() => apiHelper.Object, Lifestyle.Transient);

      //Act
      var response = await testServer.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/clients", CreateObject());

      //Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
}
```

I found [this](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/changing-configuration-at-runtime/) in the structure-map documentation but it doesn't allow me to inject a mock object in there (only types).

How I can inject a mock version of IShopApiHelper (Mock) when running my integration tests? (I am using the Moq library for mocking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same API structure as in the original example you can do basically the same thing as demonstrated in the linked documentation.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_Test() {
      //Arrange
      apiHelper.Setup(x => x.CreateClientAsync())
               .Returns(Task.FromResult(true);

       // Use the Inject method that's just syntactical
      // sugar for replacing the default of one type at a time    
      IOCConfig.Container.Inject<IShopApiHelper>(() => apiHelper.Object);

      //Act
      var response = await testServer.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/clients", CreateObject());

      //Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
}
```